# Usage of Spring @ConfigurationProperties gives nullpointer when running tests, JHipster app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-test

I have implemented a simple file upload routine using Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties annotation so I can load the directory from my YAML configuration file:

Service:

```
@Service
public class FileSystemStorageService implements StorageService {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileSystemStorageService.class);

private final Path pictureLocation;

@Autowired
public FileSystemStorageService(StorageProperties storageProperties) {
    pictureLocation = Paths.get(storageProperties.getUpload());
}
```

And the StorageProperties:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("nutrilife.meals")
public class StorageProperties {

    private String upload;

    public String getUpload() {
        return upload;
    }

    public void setUpload(String upload) {
        this.upload= upload;
    }
}
```

In the yaml file I have:

```
nutrilife:
    meals:
        upload: /$full_path_to_my_upload_dir
```

This works perfectly in normal Spring Boot runtime but the problem starts when I try to run my integration tests, it throws the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSystemStorageService' defined in file [/home/mmaia/git/nutrilife/build/classes/main/com/getnutrilife/service/upload/FileSystemStorageService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.getnutrilife.service.upload.FileSystemStorageService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)

...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.getnutrilife.service.upload.FileSystemStorageService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
```

So basically during tests the YAML file configuration looks like it's not being properly picked up. I am new to Spring. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the @value annotation :

```
@Value("upload")
private String upload;
```

The above answer is valid for application.properties config. 
it also works with yaml as well.

You may find your correct correct yaml config here :
[24.6 Using YAML instead of Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: the following worked:  @Value("upload") so the full impl like this works also with tests: 
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties("nutrilife.meals")
    public class StorageProperties {

    /**
     * Folder location for storing files
     */
    @Value("upload")
    private String upload; 
...

Please fix your answer to be @Value("upload") on top of the property so I can mark it as correct. 

Thank you.